# parallels bootmgr is missing windows

Tags: windows

My virtual machine has gone bang for some reason. When I launch windows in parallels (from mac) it says the following.

```
parallels bootmgr is missing windows 7.
```

Is it possible to access the hard drive from mac? I've tried to start the windows machine in safe mode and in the 'last known state' without success. I see the following when trying.

broken windows

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen Parallels forward the error message presented at the boot menu, do you have a screenshot? It sounds like your bog-standard "bootmgr is missing" error for Windows 7 though, in all cases.

Have you tried to repair your Windows installation with the automated Windows repair?

You can access that from your Windows setup DVD (or an ISO thereof, mounted to the virtual machine). Instructions on both accessing/carrying out the automated repair and advanced manual instructions are in a wiki article here: [Fixing the Windows bootloader via the setup DVD](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/) (disclosure: I wrote that article)